# Can you improve a 5-Dot Guide?

Tags: scion

Specifically, a character I've made has taken Mara Secare (from Scion: Companion) as a 5-Dot Guide, mainly for story reasons. 5 is the maximum, so I can't just improve her by buying more dots, but is there any other way to improve her so she can keep up with the band as we grow in Legend?

Comment: Hmm, all I've found so far is a Service Geas from Companion. That, however, is difficult to get without being a Tuatha de Dannan and requires DM fiat to work on a Guide.

Comment: Oh, and a Birthright Connection relic that can summon them to your location and revive them after death. Less a fix and more of a bandaid, but still worth it for just one dot.